# Class alias in scala

Tags: scala, alias

Is it possible in Scala to define `MyAlias[A]` as an alias for `MyClass[String, A]`. For example, `MyAlias[Int]` would refer to `Map[String, Int]`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Note that `Map` is a `trait`, not a `class`.

You can still alias it using the `type` keyword:

```
type StringMap[A] = Map[String, A]

val myMap: StringMap[Int] = Map("a" -> 1)
```

This can be done within the scope of a `class`, `object` or `trait` definition (and in the scope of any method or expression).

Sometimes you'll want the alias to be private to its declaring scope, purely as a convenience for your implementation code. If you want the type to be usable generally, [Package Objects](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/package_objects.html) come in useful:

```
package object mypackage {
  type StringMap[A] = Map[String, A]
}
```

Because `Map` is a trait (and associated companion object) and not a class, you won't be able to use it directly to create instances:

```
val myMap = new StringMap[Int]
// error: trait Map is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

If you alias a class, though, you can still use the `new` keyword:

```
type StringHashMap[A] = HashMap[String, A]
val myMap = new StringHashMap[Int]
```

Comment: Thanks, Map was a bad example, I meant (case) class