# Scala - aliasing a type inside a type

Tags: scala, traits

Say I have the following simple Scala definition of a trait inside a class:

```
class Foo {
  trait Bar
}

val f = new Foo
type MyAlias = f.Bar
```

This lets me alias `Bar` with `MyAlias`.  However, if I try to inline that to read `type MyAlias = (new Foo).Bar` the compile complains.  Why does it complain and is there a way to achieve this in one line?

Comment: please see explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12959947/384442

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.` operator with types in Scala is used for path-dependent types. For example, your `f.Bar` is an instance of `Bar` that has `f` as its parent. The compiler forbids `(new Foo).Bar` because it isn't a useful expression - you throw away the only `Foo` that can be used to create `Bar` instances of that type, so no value would ever be able to satisfy that alias.

What you may have wanted was `Foo#Bar`. This is not a path-dependent type. Any `Bar`, no matter what `Foo` is is associated with, is a `Foo#Bar`.

Here is an example:

```
class Foo {
  class Bar
}

val f1 = new Foo
val f2 = new Foo
val b1 = new f1.Bar
val b2 = new f2.Bar

// This won't compile, because b2 is a f2.Bar, not an f1.Bar
// val pathDependentBar: f1.Bar = b2

val FooHashBar: Foo#Bar = b1
```