# How to make aliases for the classes in scala

Tags: scala, hadoop

I am using the following code:

```
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
val status = fs.listStatus(new Path("wasb:///example/"))
status.foreach(x=> println(x.getPath)
```

from this question: [How to enumerate files in HDFS directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37903445/how-to-enumerate-files-in-hdfs-directory)

My problem is that I do not understand how to make an alias for a class and without it the code fails. I found all the classes mentioned in the code and the following code works:

```
val fs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration())
val status = fs.listStatus(new org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path("wasb:///example/"))
status
```

So the question is: How to make an alias for a class in scala? How to point Path() to org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path()?

I tried this question on Stackoverflow: [Class alias in scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10830308/class-alias-in-scala), but did not find a connection with my case.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about your term alias. I think you want to [import](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-packaging-import-examples-aliases-renaming-hiding). e.g.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
```

or more generally

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
```

Note that you *can* alias via an import, thus:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{Path => MyPath}
```

and then refer to `Path` as `MyPath`. This is particularly useful when writing code that imports 2 classes of the same name but differing packages e.g. `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`. Aliasing allows you to resolve that confusion.

Comment: You are right about what I meant. But why did `org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path` work? In Python it is not possible to use classes that are not imported.

Comment: In Scala and Java you can specify the full package name as you've done, but the 'import' is a convenience for you. Note that the class *still* has to be available via the classpath